# Launch: program does not exist in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c, debugging, visual-studio-code

While debugging a simple C program, I always get an error saying "Launch: program 'XXX' does not exist"

Note: I already have my compiler - GCC installed & I'm using Ubuntu operating system.

[image: Worspace of my Visual Studio Code displaying Error]
[image: My launch.json file]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the launch configuration from:

```
"program": "${workspaceRoot}/helloworld"
```

with:

```
"program": "${fileDirname}/helloworld"
```

This should fix your problem.

**Important:** Ensure the compiled filename in `tasks.json` is equivalent to your `"program"`'s filename.